# Parsing a datetime string that may or may not have an offset

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datetimeoffset

I am parsing an HL7 TimeStamp field, who's format is...

> YYYYMMDD[HHMM[SS[.SSSS]]][+/ -ZZZZ]

...meaning that the offset is optional.  If the offset is not supplied you need to assume the date/time value is local to the system sending the data, which could be in a different time zone than consuming systems parsing the data.  If the offset is supplied you should persist that as part of the timestamp.

So I'm either using the DateTime.ParseExact or DateTimeOffset.ParseExact, but neither data type seems to fit both use cases because if the timezone offset is supplied DateTime won't capture that, but if it is not supplied, DateTimeOffset can either assume my local oofset, not the source's or universal which would not be correct.

I think I need some way of having an offset or no offset within the same data type.  Any suggestions?

Comment: `DateTime.Kind` already should cover absolute/rel...

Comment: DateTimeOffset can capture universal time and nothing is hindering you to manually set the timezone to the system's sending the data.

Comment: I think I can offer an acceptable answer, but one question: You state that if the offset is not supplied, then assume the value is local to the system sending the data.  How is it that you know which time zone that system is in?  Is it sent separately? Is it static?  Is it offered in a particular format, and can you give an example?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.TryParseExact will take into account the timezone if it is present in the string:

From the documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If s contains time zone information, the time is converted to local time, if necessary, and the Kind property of the returned DateTime object is set to DateTimeKind.Local.

But I think the real problem is when time zone is not supplied. Then there is no way for the consumer to know the timezone of the sender so it cannot default to that value.

Comment: The issue is also that by "the time is converted to local time" you lose the original timezone which violates his requirement of "you should persist that [timezone] as part of the timestamp".